# SSL Issue in Elastic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53

I have created one ELB for one of my website in AWS (Windows). I have also imported SSL certificate for the same in AWS which was signed by Godaddy. When I launch load balancer URL with SSL it says certificate is invalid because the domain of certificate and domain of LB are different. Then I created Custom DNS name in Route 53 with one pointing to public IP of EC2 instance and one alias for ELB. Now when I launch actual SSL URL, it does not work.

Can someone tell me whats the issue?

Note: I want my URL to point to EBL.

Comment: "it does not work" please clarify.

Comment: You need to compare the domain you requested your certificate for with your actual domain.

Comment: Better suited for serverfault.com